# ggplot2 bar plot with several categorical variables with same levels

Tags: r, plot

Recently I learned to make a bar plot with errorbars using stat_summary like below.

```
library(ggplot2)
posn.d <- position_dodge(1.82)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=wt, col = factor(am), fill = factor(am)))+
         stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", position = posn.d)+
         stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, fun.args = list(mult = 1), geom = "errorbar", width = 0.1, position =posn.d)
```

[image]

But what I want to make is somewhat different.
There are more than two variables for group category with same levels.

(for example, 
group: "Option A", "Option B", "Option C".

levels for each group: 0, 1 )

Example data:

```
mtcars$OptionA=sample(0:1, 32, replace = T)
mtcars$OptionB=sample(0:1, 32, replace = T)
mtcars$OptionC=sample(0:1, 32, replace = T)
mtcars
```

I'd like to make a plot like this :
[image]

Can I make a plot like this with R?
Any help would be great. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to prepare your data before plotting. Concretely, since the `OptionA`, `OptionB` and `OptionC`have the same values, you can create a variable `option` that merges them all and then create a variable `value` with all the possible values (0 or 1). Translated into code it might be something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test = mtcars %>% select(mpg, OptionA:OptionC)

#present your test in long format
test_long <- gather(test, option, value, OptionA:OptionC)

> head(test_long)
   mpg  option value
1 21.0 OptionA     0
2 21.0 OptionA     0
3 22.8 OptionA     0
4 21.4 OptionA     0
5 18.7 OptionA     0
6 18.1 OptionA     1
```

Then you can create your `bar_plot` presenting `mpg` and `option` and filling with `value`

```
#plot
a = ggplot(test_long, aes(option, mpg, fill = value)) +   
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="identity")
a
```

The output is:[image]

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped a lot!! :)

Comment: @Amy, you are welcome. I think you could easily add `stat_summary` to the code above.